# How to relate two profile2's profile in one single form?

Tags: entities, users

I'm developing a portal, using Drupal 7, to manage the entrance of people on my building. I'm using Profile2 module and I created two profiles: "Dweller" and "Visitor".

Now my idea is to create a content type "visit" where I could register the visits that a dweller receive but how can I add two fields, one "dweller" and another "visitor" that will list the entities (persons) of each kind of profile?

Any one have a better approach for this requirements? Or any idea how to resolve it?

Tks!

Comment: are you using drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7…

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to display 2 profile on the same registration path you can use [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) and enter the same URL path in the settings. The 2 profile will be added to each other. You can also set the weight to choose which one come first.